# I have a CSS file in my App_Themes folder - how can I apply it to my web user control?

Tags: asp.net, css, user-controls, app-themes

Any help? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I think the term "web user control" does not exist. There are "web controls" and "user controls" (which indeed are "web controls") but I have never seen the term "web user control" being used officially.

Comment: That's what they are officially called in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Uups - you are correct of course. MS seems to use the term as well. Sorry about that. I have found it here: [Walkthrough: Creating a Web User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3457w616%28VS.71%29.aspx) which is the ASP.NET 1.1 documentation. Maybe this term has been revived?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you question correctly (as often if the title of the question is longer than the text...). But if you are trying to apply a skin to a custom control the following links might help.

[Themes for Custom Controls in ASP.NET](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/09/02/themes-for-custom-controls-in-asp-net.aspx) and [ASP.NET 2.0 Themes and Custom Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2007/02/16/asp-net-2-0-themes-and-custom-controls.aspx).

It comes down to have a `<%@ Register TagPrefix=...` directive in your skin file.

Regular CSS files are not "applied by you", I would say. The browser "just applies them". So if your control outputs HTML that references a style that exists in you CSS you are OK (check the source of the rendered page maybe?).